# How To Make A Function That Closes The Sidebar By Clicking Anywhere On The Screen And By Clicking On The Sidebar Button Itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Have Created A Sidebar And It Closes If Clicked On The **'X'** But I Want It To Close By Clicking Anywhere On The Screen (Except On The Scrollbar) And By Clicking On The Sidebar Button Itself.

```
/* Set the width of the sidebar to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "380px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "380px";
}

/* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">Beep Boop<br>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()" title="Close">&#10005;</a>
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9781; Beep Boop</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add a click event, where you detect the content of the sidebar onClick.

And you just add a logical 'not' (bang) operator condition of the declared content. Something like this:

```js
var sideBar = document.getElementById('mySideBar');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var sideBarIsClicked = sideBar.contains(event.target);

  if (!sideBarIsClicked) {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  }
});
```

Implement it in your `closeNav()` function.

Let me know if you need help in the comments.

Comment: I Tried Your Code But Now My Sidebar Is Not Opening And When I Inspected It, It Is Showing Something Like Uncaught Type Error And Samesite Error... So, Do You Know How I Can Fix These Errors? @MarkBurns